# Serialization of int property is presented as double?

Tags: java, android, json, moshi

I have a basic POJO with a property of type `int`.

`...
@Json(name = "partner_id") int partner_id = 1;
...`

After serialization it logs this in the JSON as:

`...
"partner_id":1.0
...`

How can I prevent conversion to `double` if I wish to send `partner_id` as `int`, the way it's modeled?

**Update**. I'm using [moshi-jsonapi](https://github.com/kirisetsz/moshi-jsonapi), a [json:api](http://jsonapi.org/)-compliant fork of [Square's Moshi](https://github.com/square/moshi).

Comment: What json library you are using?

Comment: I haven't had this issue with Moshi. Are you passing the correct class into the adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@kirisetsz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1059279/kirisetsz) was kind enough to take the time to recognize this as a bug in his library, and [published a fix](https://github.com/kirisetsz/moshi-jsonapi/issues/1). Thanks again!